# React jspdf generating blank pdf page

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I'm trying to use `jsPDF` to generate a PDF from HTML and display in the browser.

```
import React from "react";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";

const PDFGenerator = (props) => {
    //const string = props.data;

    const string = `
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>This is my PDF</p>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;

    const render = () => {
        const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
        pdf.html(string);
        var uri = pdf.output("datauri");
        return uri;
    }

    return render();
}

export default PDFGenerator;
```

When I run the code in Firefox, it returns a blank/empty pdf. On Safari, it returns the `base64` URL. How can I display this generated PDF in the browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The module jsPDF is used to convert the static HTML into PDF. And that PDF will be downloadable. If you are looking to convert the HTML page into PDF and then you want to show it on the browser you will have to use any other package. To the best of my knowledge jsPDF is only used where you want to convert the HTML into PDF and want to download it.

As you can see in the below figure. You are able to download the file after converting it. but you cannot show it in the browser.

Thanks.

PS: This image is taken from the jsPDF documentation.

[Documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLr5D.png)

Comment: What other package would you recommend?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any such package available or not. I have a trick for you. After converting the PDF and downloading the file via jsPDF you may open this PDF file using react-pdf module. But this is going to be a long work for this small task.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about generating the PDF in nodeJS with ```html-pdf-node``` and open in React, but it is also returning an blank PDF in React

Comment: Please try to use the react-pdf package. Thoroughly read its documentation and try it I hope you will get the solution. You will be needing the absolute path of the pdf to use this module. Then this module will render the pdf in react.

Comment: Here is my try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893705/generate-pdf-in-nodejs-and-open-in-react-with-react-pdf